# R: summarise multiple columns with different summation functions using dplyr results in error?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summarization

I am transforming a customer journey dataset from user aggregation level to a day level aggregation. The problem is that I cannot simply sum or mean all columns, as not all variables can be aggregated in the same way. For example, `duration` is a variable that I want to summarise via mean, while `purchase_own` is a variable that I want to summarise via sum.

I used `dplyr` to get this working, but it gives me an error. I tried the following code:

```
CJd <- CJre %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise_at(vars(purchase_own, purchase_any, CIT, 
FIT, T1:T22, devicemobile, devicefixed, purchase_comp, POS_comp, POS_own, POS_any, 
markov, first_touch, last_touch, linear_touch), sum) 
%>% summarise_at(vars(duration, difference), mean) %>% summarise_at(CountTP, max)
```

This results in an error:

```r
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'duration' not found
```

I suspect that this means that `summarise_at(vars(duration, difference), mean)` is not allowed as second summarise code. Now my question is, how can I write the summarise function so that summation is different for some variables?

Actual results is that only the first `summarise_at` gets executed, which results in missing variables in my dataset. The missing variables need to be summarised with `mean` and `max`, respectively. The expected outcome is these variables grouped by `date` and summarised by the named functions mean or max are added to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after the first `summarise_at`  which didn't include 'duration', therefore, the column is not there in the summarised data.  Instead, if we use `mutate_at`, and create a column, then get the `distinct` rows of the data and `summarise`

```
CJre %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(purchase_own, purchase_any, CIT, 
               FIT, T1:T22, devicemobile, devicefixed, purchase_comp, 
               POS_comp, POS_own, POS_any, 
              markov, first_touch, last_touch, linear_touch), sum) %>%
  group_by(purchase_own, purchase_any, CIT, 
           FIT, T1:T22, devicemobile, devicefixed, purchase_comp,
            POS_comp, POS_own, POS_any, 
            markov, first_touch, last_touch, linear_touch, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(duration, difference), mean)
```

markov, first_touch, last_touch, linear_touch), sum)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more regarding the ```mutate_at``` suggestion with regard to summarization of columns using different functions? So how can I use ```mutate_at``` to include ```duration``` summarized via function ```mean``` instead of ```sum``` like the other columns?

Comment: @MarcvanEck  I added one option.  Please check

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution but it gave a different error:
``` Error: Column `T1:T22` must be length 383 (the group size) or one, not 156
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In T1:T22 : numerical expression has 383 elements: only the first used
2: In T1:T22 : numerical expression has 383 elements: only the first used```